# Why does this portion of google's android tutorial use "FragmentActivity"?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

It is taking me forever to learn the Android SDK. I am currently trying to implement swipe views with tabs by following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) tutorial.

I understand that we are supposed to use fragments as "mini activities", and that one fragment makes up of the many tabs attached to the ViewPager.

There is this code segment in the tutorial that I fail to grasp, however:

```
    public class CollectionDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // When requested, this adapter returns a DemoObjectFragment,
    // representing an object in the collection.
    DemoCollectionPagerAdapter mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_collection_demo);

        // ViewPager and its adapters use support library
        // fragments, so use getSupportFragmentManager.
        mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter =
                new DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(
                        getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Does the FragmentActivity class come into play when attaching a Fragment to the ViewPager? In separate documentations of fragments and viewpagers, I cannot find mention of FragmentActivity.

I would really appreciate it if you could shed some light on this matter.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Adapter takes this as an argument: `getSupportFragmentManager()`

That is only available to a [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()). (specifically, of the Support library variety).